# Is there any API in Twisted for downloading mail attachment using IMAP4?

Tags: python, twisted, attachment, fetch

I'm learning Twisted and trying to download some mails from my own mailbox. One important task is to save all MS-EXCEL attachments to my computer using IMAP4. I know there're a bunch of "fetch*" APIs in twisted.mail.imap4 to act the fetch command. However, I'm curious about is there any API in Twisted that can download attachment from the mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Twisted imap4 client mostly follows the underlying protocol semantics and offers few conveniences above that.  You'll need to use `fetchMessage`, and then decode the Message yourself, with something like [`email.message_from_file()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_file)